# Viewing variables within a java object in the logs

Tags: java, android, json

I have a really simple wrapper class thats displayed below:

```
public class EmbedFoods {

    private Collection<Food> foods;

    public Collection<Food> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public void setFoods(Collection<Foods> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}

public class Food {

    private String nutrition;
    private String calories;
    private String peanuts;

    etc...

}
```

I get a list of "Food" for this EmbedFoods class by calling my API which returns a JSON string and I use Robospice for Spring Android to populate EmbedFoods automatically.

Now, I would like to view the object EmbedFoods in a human-readable format, preferably JSON.

If I go `Log.e("embedFoods", EmbedFoods.toString());`, it returns:

> E/embedFoods [LModel.Food;@25ef9bbb

I can only see the model that is inside the embedFood class, but I cannot see variables that it comprises of. I was hoping to see a JSON string that shows all the variable of the java object printed in the logs.

How can I view all the variables that were set within the embedFood class other than debugging the line in which the embedFood is set in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Well a way to do this can be done by overriding the toString method to display the correct values you want to see.

Something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Foods[] foods = collection.toArray();

    String words = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
        words = words + "{" + foods.nutrition + foods.etc + "}"
    }
    words = words + "]"
    return words;
}
```

In your Embed foods.